# Step by step instructions for adding a block to the shopping cart in Magento 2

Tags: cart, blocks, shopping

Can anyone provide a link or write out step-by-step instruction for adding a link to the Magento 2 shopping cart page?  I have tried following several provided by 3rd parties, but I haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's depends on where you need to add. So for now, let's assume you want to add this link in content container.

You have to add code in app/design//<theme_dir>/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

Code :

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block name="block_name" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Contact Us</argument>
            <argument name="href" xsi:type="string">testlink</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">testlink</argument>         
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

If this help you to build your logic then hit like :)

Enjoy your coding !!! :)

Thank you
Hiren Patel

Comment: If I have a specific block already created ond working on other pages, can I use that?

Comment: Yes, you can use it.
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block name="block_name" class="<block_class>" template="Module_Name::test.phtml">
    </block>
</referenceContainer>

Comment: I have followed your suggestion, Hiren, and it is working.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.